# How to import local powershell modules without looping?

Tags: powershell, module

Say I have many `.ps1` scripts into `\src\scripts\`.

Say I have many `.psm1` modules containing exportable functions into `\src\lib\`.

Now, I have, say `script.ps1` importing function `mail` exported from `\src\lib\mailing.psm1`

Say I have also `log` a function exported from `\src\lib\logging.psm1`.

I need to call `mail fm to cc` from `script.ps1`.

I try to design `mail` in a manner that it can also `log` from `\src\lib\logging.psm1`.

So I decided to load `\src\lib\*.psm1` into `script.ps1`.

When I import `\src\lib\logging.psm1` into `\src\lib\mailing.psm1` it works, obsviously.

What if I now want `log` to use `mail` ? I tried to first look if the module is already imported then import it if not.

But, how the hell can I design a robust method to import all `*.psm1` into all my `*.ps1` **while** importing all *.psm1 but themselves into each other ?

I tried manifests methods and this little code :

```
$moduleFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "A:\bsolute\path_here" -Filter *.psm1
foreach ($moduleFile in $moduleFiles) {
    $MyInvocation
     if ($moduleFile.Name -ne $MyInvocation.Mycommand){
        if ($moduleFile.Name -notin $(Get-Module)){
         Import-Module -Name $moduleFile.FullName -Verbose -Force
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: If `log` depends on `mail`, then `logging.psm1` should import `mailing.psm1`

Comment: To add to Mathias' comment: you can formalize module dependencies if you create your modules as full-fledged, directory-based modules that come with a [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, yes but logging needs to call mailing who calls again log ...

Comment: Is it possible for a module into a manifest to call functions of all others ?